# tkinter - Is there a similar wait_window() method that lets "parent window" to get "child window"'s attributes before it destroys itself?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a main window that creates a `Toplevel` window instance as one of its attribute and the control of application moves to it. This child window does a series of work and collects data in one of its attributes (for example a `list` variable). I need this attribute after the child window is closed (destroyed).

```
class MainWindow(tkinter.Tk())
    ...
    self.cw=ChildWindow()
    self.wait_window()
```

Need to use `self.cw.list` here.

```
class ChildWindow(Toplevel):
    ...
    self.list
    ...
    self.destroy()
```

If instead of waiting for destruction of child window, it, for example, waited for the child window to be hidden (`withdraw()` method) then parent window would have opportunity to grab the attributes and then destroy the child window itself. I don't want to send another parameter when instantiating the child window nor use a global variable.

How can I neatly doing this?

Comment: It's little unclear what is your problem. Destruction of `TopLevel` has no effect on your list, because `ChildWindow` isn't destroyed (of course it's not true if you destroy widget in class destructor, but there's no code in your question). Also you're already implicitly send a root to `Toplevel`, because there's no widgets without parent, so feel free to send an instance of `MainWindow` explicitly.

Comment: Since `ChildWindow` is a subclass of `TopLevel`, you could override the its inherited `withdraw()` method. However to do what you want would require another constructor variable or a global—so your restrictions seem unreasonable. What about adding another method to pass that information into the instance?

Comment: In other words, with your current design, while your keep a reference to an instance in `self.cw` you able to reach a `self.cw.list` no matter what. Also, if in future you decide to deal with this behaviour - overriding of inherited methods is very good option (as @martineau mentioned).

Comment: Thank you all that generously took your time and try to help me through my shaky question. I guess @CommonSense truly got me to the simple point I was strangely missing. I just need to keep a reference to that required attribute immediately after creating the instance. It's just common sense you know ;)